# General approach of signal detection after demodulation of BPSK

Tags: detection, demodulation, bpsk

I'm very new to electrical engineering. I'm trying to understand the basic approaches/options to detect symbols after demodulation of BPSK. I found some articles mentioning Maximum Likelihood detection (http://ecelabs.njit.edu/sdr/lab3/overview.pdf). Are there other options? With Maximum Likelihood detection, are there other required parameters needed besides the signal data?

Comment: Please link to the article you read.

Comment: http://ecelabs.njit.edu/sdr/lab3/overview.pdf